# Draping 2d point on a 3d terrain

Tags: opengl, 3d

I am using OpenTK(OpenGL) and a general hint will be helpful.

I have a 3d terrain. I have one point on this terrain O(x,y,z) and two perpendicular lines passing through this point that will serve as my X and Y axes.

Now I have a set of 2d points with are in polar coordinates (range,theta). I need to find which points on the terrain correspond to these points. I am not sure what is the best way to do it. I can think of two ideas:

Lets say I am drawing A(x1,y1).

1. Find the intersection of plane passing through O and A which is perpendicular to the XY plane. This will give me a polyline (semantics may be off). Now on this line, I find a point that is visible from O and is at a distance of the range.
2. Create a circle which is perpendicular to the XY plane with radius "range", find intersection points on the terrain, find which ones are visible from O and drop rest.

I understand I can find several points which satisfy the conditions, so I will do further check based on topography, but for now I need to get a smaller set which satisfy this condition.

I am new to opengl, but I get geometry pretty well. I am wondering if something like this exists in opengl since it is a standard problem with ground measuring systems.

Comment: what is OPENTK? do you mean opengl?

Comment: yes sir. i will edit.

Comment: So you basically want to find the height of some point on the terrain? That depends on how you represent the terrain.

Comment: i can choose what is easier for the purpose.

Comment: OpenGL's concern is rendering, and it doesn't include any such utilities. Generally you need to write or make use of a math library in combination with OpenGL. For OpenTK, this would be OpenTK.Math. [A cursory inspection](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/search?utf8=✓&q=polar) doesn't show any functions dealing with polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, both of the options you present will give you more than the one point you need. As I understand your problem, you need only to perform a change of bases from polar coordinates `(r, angle)` to cartesian coordinates `(x,y)`.

This is fairly straight forward to do. Assuming that the two coordinate spaces share the origin O and that the angle is measured from the x-axis, then point `(r_i, angle_i)` maps to `x_i = r_i*cos(angle_i)` and `y_i = r_i*sin(angle_i)`. If those assumptions aren't correct (i.e. if the origins aren't coincident or the angle is not measured from a `radii` parallel to the x-axis), then the transformation is a bit more complicated but can still be done.

If your terrain is represented as a height map, or 2D array of heights (e.g. `Terrain[x][y] = z`), once you have the point in cartesian coordinates `(x_i,y_i)` you can find the height at that point. Of course `(x_i, y_i)` might not be exactly one of the `[x]` or `[y]` indices of the height map.

In that case, I think you have a few options:

- Choose the closest `(x,y)` point and take that height; or
- Interpolate the height at `(x_i,y_i)` based on the surrounding points in the height map.

Unfortunately I am also learning `OpenGL` and can not provide any specific insights there, but I hope this helps solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your description I see a bit of confusion... maybe.

You have defined point O(x,y,z). Fine, this is your pole for the 3D coordinate system. Then you want to find a point defined by polar coordinates. That's fine also - it gives you 2D location. Basically all you need to do is to pinpoint the location in 3D A'(x,y,0), because we are assuming you know the elevation of the A at (r,t), which you of course do from the terrain there.

Angle (t) can be measured only from one axis. Choose which axis will be your polar north and stick to. Then you measure r you have and - voila! - you have your location. What's the point of having 2D coordinate set if you don't use it? Instead, you're adding visibility to the mix - I assume it is important, but highest terrain point on azimuth (t) NOT NECESSARILY will be in the range (r).

You have specific coordinates. Just like RonL suggest, convert to (x,y), find (z) from actual terrain and be done with it.

Unless that's not what you need. But in that case a different question is in order: what do you look for?